# What benefits come from using Progressive Web Apps (PWA) guidelines?

Tags: single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

I was reading about advantages of PWAs, but I really can't understand why we have to use this technology. Is this similar to SPA? Or this is completely something else?

Comment: Progressive web enhancement (I've not heard of "progressive web apps" as a "technology" per se) had everything to do with handling users who had browser with spotty standards support (looking at you, Internet Explorer), and for those who did not have Javascript enabled (meaning the site would still at least be minimally useful). This seems to be less of an issue these days for the former, and making a "web-based application" useful for never-scripters may be counter-productive (think Slack if it had only hard links and POSTBACK forms). As always, YMMV.

Comment: I also changed the title to make it less provocative. The underlying question I think is good and certainly answerable.

Answer (score 16):

A **Single Page Application (SPA)** can be a **Progressive Web App (PWA)** but a PWA doesn't need to be a SPA.  They are two different things.  A PWA as defined by Google is:

**Reliable** - Load instantly and never show the downasaur, even in uncertain network conditions.
**Fast** - Respond quickly to user interactions with silky smooth animations and no janky scrolling.
**Engaging** - Feel like a natural app on the device, with an immersive user experience.

The Google PWA site is a good place to start learning about PWA and why and how you would build one.

https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

A SPA is simply a web app where a single page is loaded in the browser and all subsequent routing and page view rendering is handled on the client (browser) using JavaScript.

Properly combining the principles of PWA and SPA can result in a much improved user experience especially on mobile phones with unreliable internet connections.

Probably the best example today of a well implemented PWA is Twitter Lite.  Check it out here:

https://mobile.twitter.com/home

...and read about it here:

https://blog.twitter.com/en_us/topics/product/2017/introducing-twitter-lite.html

Comment: Looking at the Google page, this really seems more of the "pure web" application built with technology from the browser, but not necessarily for the browser. In other words, how to make a "native-like" app your users will use on mobile with browser-based techniques. To wit, this is why Facebook dumped HTML5 for *real* native apps 5-6 years ago.

Comment: Here is the "don't be stupid" checklist for building a native-like app, from Google: https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist

Answer (score 3):

A SPA is something different than a PWA. You can view PWA as an enhancement of your website. By adding a [service worker](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/) and a [manifest](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/) you can bring your website (SPA or not) out of the browser, work like a mobile app and make it perform better.